# In C#, what's the difference between \n and \r\n?

Tags: c#, newline, linefeed, carriage-return

In C#, what's the difference between `\n` and `\r\n`?

Comment: This is unrelated to C# as it would be applicable in almost all languages.

Comment: @leppie The answer may *coincidentally* apply to other languages. But other languages are free to do whatever they want.

Comment: Dont use any of the two above. Simply use Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`\n` is Unix, `\r` is Mac, `\r\n` is Windows.

Sometimes it's giving trouble especially when running code cross platform. You can bypass this by using `Environment.NewLine`.

Please refer to [What is the difference between \r, \n and \r\n ?!](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/47af2197-26b4-4b9e-90e8-bfa9d5cd05b4) for more information. Happy reading

Comment: Because nowadays Windows is not as strict in this as it use to be, so it accepts \n as well.

Comment: @TobySmith I know this post is old, but you can try writing a file with "\n" as linebreak and open it with the standard Windows Editor. He will not do a linebreak unless you did "\r\n"

Comment: In Windows 10, support for all types of line endings is added in Notepad! https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/

Answer (score 42):

> The Difference

There are a few characters which can indicate a new line. The usual ones are these two:

```
* '\n' or '0x0A' (10 in decimal) -> This character is called "Line Feed" (LF).
* '\r' or '0x0D' (13 in decimal) -> This one is called "Carriage return" (CR).
```

Different Operating Systems handle newlines in a different way. Here is a short list of the most common ones:

```
* DOS and Windows
```

They expect a newline to be the combination of two characters, namely '\r\n' (or 13 followed by 10).

```
* Unix (and hence Linux as well)
```

Unix uses a single '\n' to indicate a new line.

```
* Mac
```

Macs use a single `'\r'`.

Taken from [Here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8021)

Comment: AFAIK, Macs haven't used `\r` since OSX -- they use `\n` now.  And `\r\n` happens to be used by just about every app-layer internet protocol in existence that ever works in terms of lines.

Answer (score 14):

"\n" is just a line feed (Unicode U+000A). This is typically the Unix line separator.

"\r\n" is a carriage return (Unicode U+000D) followed by a line feed (Unicode U+000A). This is typically the Windows line separator.

Comment: Jon but if it's only line feed , so why the text in the pic looks like it also has carrige return http://i.stack.imgur.com/LKVCr.png  ? if it was only a line feed so the _bbb..._ should not be at most left of the second line...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It all depends on the display medium. So it looks like the Windows console shell treats `\n` as a complete line break now, but it may not in all versions - and if you view that same data as a file in notepad, you *won't* see a line break.

Answer (score 4):

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character on Unix

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character on Mac

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character on Windows

(char)13 = \r =  CR

**Environment.NewLine** = any of the above code based on the operating system

// .NET provides the Environment class which provides many data based on operating systems, so if the application is built on Windows, and you use CR + LF ("\n\r" instead of Environment.NewLine) as the new line character in your strings, and then Microsoft creates a VM for running .NET applications in Unix, then there will be problem. **So, you should always use Environment.NewLine when you want a new line character.** Now you need not to care about the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Basically comes down to Windows standard: \r\n and Unix based systems using: \n

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 0):

It's about how the operating system recognizes line ends.

- Windows user \r\n
- Mac user \r
- Linux uses \n

Morale: if you are developing for Windows, stick to \r\n. Or even better, use C# string functions to deal with strings which already consider line endings (WriteLine, and such).

Answer (score 0):

\n is the line break used by Unix(-like) systems, \r\n is used by windows. This has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 0):

They are just `\r\n and \n` are variants.

`\r\n` is used in windows

`\n` is used in mac and linux

Answer (score 0):

- `\r` inserts [<kbd>U+000D</kbd>CARRIAGE RETURN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm)
- `\n` inserts [<kbd>U+000A</kbd>LINE FEED](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm)

You can insert one, or the other, or both:

- `\r\n` inserts <kbd>U+000D</kbd><kbd>U+000A</kbd>
- `\n\r` inserts <kbd>U+000A</kbd><kbd>U+000D</kbd>

If you intention is to indicate *"the end of the line"*, different platforms, and different technologies, expect you to insert different things:

- Windows: <kbd>U+000D</kbd><kbd>U+000A</kbd> *(i.e. `\r\n`)*
- HTTP: <kbd>U+000D</kbd><kbd>U+000A</kbd> *(i.e. `\r\n`)*
- HTML: <kbd>U+000A</kbd> *(i.e. `\n`)*
- Unix: <kbd>U+000A</kbd> *(i.e. `\n`)*
- Macintosh: <kbd>U+000D</kbd> *(i.e. `\r`)*
- zOS: <kbd>U+0085</kbd> *(i.e. `\x85`)*